# Setting proxy in browser using javascript and Cypress

Tags: javascript, proxy, cypress

I am able to set the proxy in chrome browser using the below java code:

```java
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");

proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8090");
proxy.setFtpProxy("localhost:8090");
proxy.setSslProxy("localhost:8090");

options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Now, I am using Cypress with javascript and want to do the same as I did above.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For adding `http proxy`, you can set `HTTP_PROXY` environmental variable.

for mac:

```
export HTTP_PROXY = localhost:8090
```

for windows

```
set HTTP_PROXY = localhost:8090
```

And for ignoring certificate errors, you can disable `chromeWebSecurity` in `cypress.json` file

```json
{ 
  "chromeWebSecurity": false
}
```

[reference document](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration#Set-a-proxy-on-Linux-or-macOS)

Comment: Do I need to fire "set HTTP_PROXY = localhost:8090" from command line or from Cypress javascript code? Can it not be done from javascript?

Comment: you can pass it as an argument while running tests, or set value in the cypress.json file as an environmental parameter

Comment: Can you please shoe me with some example how one can pass it as an argument while running tests, or set value in the cypress.json file as an environmental parameter. That will be a great help! Thanks

Comment: Please go through https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Setting

Comment: the link describes how you can set and use the variable values in your test. I do not want to use the value of HTTP_PROXY in my test. I want to set the proxy for my tests to run. It does not help :( I have set it manually in computer's environment variable which cypress detects and shows in the test runner - Settings - Proxy Settings. However, setting the value using environment-variables does not reflect the proxy settings in the Cypress test runner - Settings -Proxy settings section. That is the reason I asked if you have done it then you can share how you did it.